# How to change the colour of fillstyle for the border of the solid gauge?

Tags: javascript, charts, gauge, lightningchart

In LightningchartJS gauges how can I change the colour of the borders of the gauge?

```
const gauge = lightningChart().Gauge({ type: GaugeChartTypes.Solid })
.setTitle('Annual sales goal')
.setThickness(80)
.setDataLabelFormater(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }))
.setGaugeStrokeStyle(new SolidLine().setFillStyle(new SolidFill()).setThickness(1))
.setAngleInterval(225, -45)

// Create slice
const slice = gauge
.getDefaultSlice()
.setInterval(0, 400000)
.setValue(329000)
.setFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(12, 213, 87) }))
.setName('2019 sales')
```

Answer (score 1):

At line 5 you are setting the styles of your gauge's stroke (what I guess you call the "border").
That's where you can pass a [color](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.1.0/classes/color.html) option to the [`SolidFill`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.1.0/classes/solidfill.html) constructor:

```
.setGaugeStrokeStyle(
  new SolidLine()
    .setFillStyle(
      new SolidFill( {
        color: ColorHEX('#00F')
      } )
    ).setThickness(1)
)
```

But you'd need to import the ColorXXX component too.